# Live OS freezes on purple screen

Tags: boot-failure, live-usb

I am also facing same problem. I have already installed opensuse, fedora17(facing some problems so deleted). But 12.04 is giving me issues. I was able to install 10.04 on my machine by wubi. Later on I have tried all the versions of Ubuntu but unable to get it worked. Please help me I am starving here, I want to use Unity :'(

Or help me installing UNITY on my OPENSUSE12.01.

I tried same copy  on Dell Inspiron by my USB and it's booted in few seconds but my laptop doesn't.

One more thing I would like to mention. My all OS's(except Windows :P) freezes after installtion till the installation of graphics driver of 'nVidia 8200m' by command line.